# Passing arguments to helper functions for each Meteor template instance

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, qr-code, meteor-blaze

I'm creating a meteor page that lists a series of images sitting in a mongo database, as such:

```
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h3>List of Uploaded Images</h3>
  </header>
  <table align="center" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <th> Timestamp </th>
    <th> Public URL </th>
    <th> QR Code</th>
    <th> Session ID </th>
    <th> Filename </th>
    </tr>
      {{#each getImages}}
        {{> image}}
      {{/each}}
</table>
</div>

</body>

<template name="image">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"> {{ displayDate createdAt }} </td>
    <td align="center"> {{ publicUrl }} </td>
    <td align="center"><canvas id="qrcode"></canvas></td>
    <td align="center"> {{ sessionId }} </td>
    <td align="center"> {{ fileName }} </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

I also have a `onRendered` helper function for the image template:

```
Template.image.onRendered(function() {
  $('#qrcode').qrcode({
    size: 128,
    text: "https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/my-image-name.jpg"
  });
});
```

And this works great, in that it renders a QR Code that encodes a URL to a single image on my storage bucket.

My question is: how can I change this template and helper, so that for *each* instance of the template, I create a unique qr code that encodes the variable `publicUrl` ?

Ideally, I would change the helper to be:

```
Template.image.onRendered(function(myUrl) {
  $('#qrcode').qrcode({
    size: 128,
    text: myUrl
  });
});
```

and then from the template I could pass the argument `publicUrl` to it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Currently you are setting the qrcode parameters (size and text) via jquery. Can it be done via html as well? Eg. ```<canvas id="qrcode" size=128 text="someurl"></canvas>``` Also, can you please post the current image template's helper?

Comment: Using `#qrcode` as a selector is going to select *all* your canvases at once. Would be better to use a unique ID for each canvas. The `text` option should work as per the qrdocde docs and example.

Comment: It seems that the qrcode is ONLY generated by the text passed into the option, NOT be the text set as a parameter... if I do it like above, then all qrCodes decode to the default "no text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to blueren for putting me on the right track!

The trick was to give each canvas a unique id (so I could select it with jquery), and then to use `Template.instance().data` to access the variables in the `onRendered()` function.

**Template:**

```
<template name="image">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"> {{ displayDate createdAt }} </td>
    <td align="center"> {{ publicUrl }} </td>
    <td align="center"><canvas id={{ sessionId }}></canvas></td>
    <td align="center"> {{ sessionId }} </td>
    <td align="center"> {{ fileName }} </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

**OnRendered:**

```
Template.image.onRendered(function() {
  var selector = "#" + Template.instance().data.sessionId;
  $(selector).qrcode({
    size: 128,
    radius: 0.0,
    text: Template.instance().data.publicUrl
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Template:**

```
...
...
...
<template name="image">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"> {{ displayDate createdAt }} </td>
    <td align="center"> {{ publicUrl }} </td>
    <td align="center"><canvas id="qrcode" text={{qrcodeUrl}}></canvas></td>
    <td align="center"> {{ sessionId }} </td>
    <td align="center"> {{ fileName }} </td>
  </tr>
</template>
...
...
...
```

**Helper:**

```
Template.image.helpers({

    qrCodeUrl: function(){
             // get the qr-code url from wherever you need to and have it returned. Need to see your current helper class in order to help put more code here.

    return qrCodeUrl;

    }

});
```

**OnRendered:**

```
Template.image.onRendered(function(myUrl) {
  $('#qrcode').qrcode({
    size: 128
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems like the text for the qrcode actually needs to be passed in through the options in $().qrcode(); otherwise all qrcodes display the default "no text"

Comment: I also don't have any current helper functions other than the `onRendered()` function.